# How use mybatis to update table field where the type is list

Tags: java, jdbc, mybatis

table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `policy` (
    `id`         VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL COMMENT '策略ID',
    `name`       VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL COMMENT '策略名',
    `version`    VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '策略版本',
    `statements` VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL COMMENT '策略表达式',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC COMMENT='策略';
```

mybatis config file:

```
    <typeHandlers>
        <typeHandler handler="io.github.ctlove0523.toyiam.server.model.storage.handler.PolicyStatementsHandler"
                     javaType="List"/>
    </typeHandlers>
```

PolicyStatementsHandler:

```
public class PolicyStatementsHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<List<PolicyStatement>> {
    @Override
    public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, int i, List<PolicyStatement> policyStatements, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
        preparedStatement.setString(i, JacksonUtil.object2Json(policyStatements));
    }

    @Override
    public List<PolicyStatement> getNullableResult(ResultSet resultSet, String s) throws SQLException {
        return JacksonUtil.json2List(resultSet.getString(s), PolicyStatement.class);
    }

    @Override
    public List<PolicyStatement> getNullableResult(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
        return JacksonUtil.json2List(resultSet.getString(i), PolicyStatement.class);
    }

    @Override
    public List<PolicyStatement> getNullableResult(CallableStatement callableStatement, int i) throws SQLException {
        return JacksonUtil.json2List(callableStatement.getString(i), PolicyStatement.class);
    }
}
```

PolicyMapper.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="io.github.ctlove0523.toyiam.server.model.storage.mapper.PolicyMapper">

    <resultMap id="policyResultMap" type="Policy">
        <id property="id" column="id"/>
        <result property="name" column="name"/>
        <result property="version" column="version"/>
        <result property="statements" column="statements" typeHandler="io.github.ctlove0523.toyiam.server.model.storage.handler.PolicyStatementsHandler"/>
    </resultMap>

    <insert id="savePolicy" parameterType="Policy">
        INSERT INTO policy(id,name,version,statements)
        VALUE(#{id},#{name},#{version},#{statements})
    </insert>

    <update id="updateVersionAndStatements">
        UPDATE policy
        SET statements = #{statements},version = #{version}
        WHERE id = #{id}
    </update>

</mapper>
```

PolicyMapper.java

```
public interface PolicyMapper {

    void savePolicy(Policy policy);

    void updateVersionAndStatements(@Param("id") String id, @Param("version") String version, @Param("statements") List<PolicyStatement> statements);
}
```

problem:
savePolicy method works well but updateVersionAndStatements throw exception: Type java.util.ArrayList not supported type.
How should i do to fix this problem?
Error Stack:

```
==>  Preparing: UPDATE policy SET statements = ?,version = ? WHERE id = ?
Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@34a9f817]
2022-08-06 14:52:15.522 ERROR 11512 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not set parameters for mapping: ParameterMapping{property='statements', mode=IN, javaType=class java.lang.Object, jdbcType=null, numericScale=null, resultMapId='null', jdbcTypeName='null', expression='null'}. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #1 with JdbcType null . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #1 with JdbcType null . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Type java.util.ArrayList not supported type] with root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Type java.util.ArrayList not supported type
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.BasePreparedStatement.setInternalObject(BasePreparedStatement.java:1103) ~[mariadb-java-client-3.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.BasePreparedStatement.setObject(BasePreparedStatement.java:644) ~[mariadb-java-client-3.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.setObject(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.PreparedStatementLogger.invoke(PreparedStatementLogger.java:67) ~[mybatis-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy78.setObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.ObjectTypeHandler.setNonNullParameter(ObjectTypeHandler.java:31) ~[mybatis-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler.setParameter(BaseTypeHandler.java:73) ~[mybatis-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.UnknownTypeHandler.setNonNullParameter(UnknownTypeHandler.java:67) ~[mybatis-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
```

Comment: Please add the full stack trace.

Comment: @ave already add error stack info

Comment: Currently, you need to specify the type handler explicitly. `#{statements,typeHandler=io.github.ctlove0523.toyiam.server.model.storage.handler.PolicyStatementsHandler}`. It's a kind of limitation.